Send Firebase Remote Notification with http v1 API from Swift, iOS
I am trying to receive an access token using AppAuth for swift.  The code i used will return an error:

Initiating authorization request with scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging Authorization
error: Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden.
(org.openid.appauth.general-Fehler -3.)

The client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri are from google cloud console (OAuth 2.0-Client-IDs -> Web client (auto created by Google Service)).
See this Screenshot: google cloud console
Edit:
When sending the request in my App, an alert opens and then immediately closes again, asking me if i want to grant permission for google.com to log in.
Maybe this Error Message is related to it:

"2024-10-30 18:23:57.498706+0100 Student App[97110:15504024] [Warning]
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
(<SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x108829800>)"

   import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import AppAuth
import AppAuthCore


class RemoteNotificationSender: UIViewController {
    func sendPushNotification(to topicPath: String, title: String, body: String) {
        
        // property of the containing class
        var authState: OIDAuthState?
        var access_token = ""
        
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        
        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fau-students/messages:send"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
            
          
            
            let paramString: [String : Any] = ["message" : ["topic": "weather",
                                           "notification" : [
                                            "title" : title,
                                                             "body" : body
                                           ],
                                           "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
        ]
                                               ]
            
          

               let MESSAGING_SCOPE =
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
               let scopes = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];
        
       

            
        let authorizationEndpoint = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")!
        let tokenEndpoint = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")!
        let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint,
                                                    tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint)

           
            
            
            
            // perform the auth request...
            // builds authentication request
        
            let request_ = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration,
                                                   clientId: "<CLIENT_ID FROM OAUTH2.0 WEB CLIENT>",
                                                   clientSecret: "<CLIENT_SECRET FROM WEB CLIENT>",
                                                   scopes: scopes,
                                                   redirectURL: URL(string: "<REDIRECT_URI FROM WEB CLIENT>")!,
                                                   responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode,
                                                   additionalParameters: nil)
            
            // performs authentication request
            print("Initiating authorization request with scope: \(request_.scope ?? "nil")")
            
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            
            appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow =
            OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request_ , presenting: self) { authState, error in
                if let authState = authState {
                    //self.setAuthState(authState)
                    
                    print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: " +
                          "\(authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken ?? "nil")")
                    access_token = authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken ?? "nil"
                } else {
                    print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                    //self.setAuthState(nil)
                }
            }
        
        
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer " + access_token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = data {
                    if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        NSLog("FCM: Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                    }
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
        
        
        //})
    }
}


Edit: I Made this Approach, using AppAuth. If you know any other Approach for getting an Access token from Swift, please describe it in Detail.
Approach using Almofire
Example using Google Auth Library in Flutter

It is not secure to embed client credentials in your app. Your app should send a request to a server (eg a cloud function) that has access to the credentials. It can then send the notification.

@Paulw11 please provide a detailed example of how to implement a solution into swift.
